# Please merge my accounts fossfreedom and user16600

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-accounts

I've seemed to have created two accounts - I dont use https://askubuntu.com/users/16600/user16600 but I do use my openID account launchpad.net/~fossfreedom

Please can these be merged - or just delete account "16600"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there aren't any posts or reputation on `user16600`, I went ahead and deleted the account for you. Thanks for letting us know, it always helps to keep the site clean.